# css misbehaves in ie 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-float

My CSS validates on W3C and I have proper container divs and child divs and have float elements within child divs.

The following CSS works in Firefox and Chrome. But cant make out why ie9 dislikes it or vice versa.

The CSS :

```
.container{margin:0px auto;width:1200px;border:1px solid #e5e4e2;}

.toppanel{width:1200px;text-align:center;height:100px;background-color:#a1b8a3;margin-top:-20px}

.lpanel{float:left;width:250px;height:1000px;border:1px solid #e5e4e2;background-color:#233245;padding:10px;color:white}
.lpanel2{width:190px;height:500px;margin:0px auto;background-color:white;color:maroon;padding:20px;text-align:center;}

.rpanel{float:right;width:250px;height:1000px;border:1px solid #e5e4e2;background-color:#e4e5e2;padding:10px}
.rpanel1{width:250px;margin:0px auto;}.rpanel2{margin:0px auto;width:250px;}

.midpanel{width:800px;height:1000px;border:1px solid #e5e4e2;margin:0px auto;background-color:beige}
.middle1{margin:0px auto;width:800px;}.middlemainimg{padding:10px;}.middlemainimg img{margin:10px;width:270px;height:255px}
.middle1r{float:right;width:300px;height:205px;background-color:white;margin-top:-280px;margin-right:10px;padding:20px}

.middle2{margin:0px auto;width:750px;text-align:center;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:5px}
.middle3{margin:0px auto;width:600px;margin-top:15px}
.middle4{margin:0px auto;padding:10px;margin-top:0px;float:left;margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;width:250px}
.middle4r{margin-left:300px;width:470px;background-color:white;height:170px;margin-top:40px}
.middlelast{margin:0px auto;width:750px;height:250px;background-color:white;margin-top:20px;padding:20px;text-align:center;}
.middlelast img{margin-left:30px;width:120px;height:90px;}

.bottompanel{clear:both;width:1200px;height:100px;border:1px solid #e5e4e2;text-align:center;background-color:#cccccc}
.bottompanel ul li{display:inline;margin:10px}

.imgcar {width:140px;height:60px;padding:2px;border:2px solid grey;cursor:pointer;}

#carousel {
        width: 600px;
        overflow:hidden;
        height:75px;
        background-color:white;
    }

    #carousel ul {
        width: 1600px;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 0;
        height:75px;
    }

    #carousel ul li {
        width:750px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 30px;
        list-style: none;
        float:  left;
            }
```

The HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title>NA Plots on Murbad-Karjat Highway</title>
    <meta name="title" content="NA Plots on Murbad-Karjat Highway" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="application-name" content="Landshoppe.com - The Free Property Site" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tooltip" content="Landshoppe.com - The Free Property Site" />
    <meta name="msapplication-window" content="width=1500;height=900" />
    <meta name="msapplication-task"
    content="name=Search property;action-uri=http://www.landshoppe.com/;icon-uri= http://www.landshoppe.com/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="msapplication-task"
    content="name=Property Search;action-uri=http://www.landshoppe.com/searchdetails;icon-uri= http://www.landshoppe.com/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="msapplication-task"
    content="name=Property Registration;action-uri=http://www.landshoppe.com/registration;icon-uri= http://www.landshoppe.com/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="msapplication-task"
    content="name=Landshoppe Log in;action-uri=http://www.landshoppe.com/Login;icon-uri= http://www.landshoppe.com/favicon.ico" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="8206EB8E37D990E86837A5ED472D65A3" />
    <meta name="author" content="landshoppe" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="Reply-to" content="anit@landshoppe.com" />
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="noodp,INDEX,FOLLOW" />
    <meta name="creation_Date" content="09/30/2012" />
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="1 days" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="Landshoppe" />
    <meta name="classification" content="Real Estate, Properties, Real Estate Agents, Search Property Online" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="image1013.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="LANDSHOPPE RSS Feed" href="http://www.landshoppe.com/feed.xml" />
    <link href='apple_image1013.JPG' rel='apple-touch-icon' />
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jav.js"></script>-->
  <!--[if lte IE 6]>
<div id="warning">
<h4 class="red">Your Browser Is Not Supported!</h4><br>
<p>Please upgrade to <a href='http://getfirefox.com'>FireFox</a>, <a href='http://www.opera.com/download/'>Opera</a>, <a href='http://www.apple.com/safari/'>Safari</a> or <a href='http://www.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/ie/getitnow.mspx'>Internet Explorer 8 or above</a>. Thank You!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('warning').style.display = 'none';"><span class='bold'>Close Window</span></a></p>
</div>
<![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte IE 7]>
<div id="warning">
<h4 class="red">Your Browser Is Not Supported!</h4>
<p>Please upgrade to <a href='http://getfirefox.com'>FireFox</a>, <a href='http://www.opera.com/download/'>Opera</a>, <a href='http://www.apple.com/safari/'>Safari</a> or <a href='http://www.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/ie/getitnow.mspx'>Internet Explorer 8 or above</a>. Thank You!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('warning').style.display = 'none';"><span class='bold'>Close Window</span></a></p>
</div>
<![endif]-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="toppanel">
    <a href="index.htm" title="The Free Property Website">
      <img src="logo.jpg" alt="The Free Property Website" style="float:left;margin:10px;width:150px;height:80px" />
    </a> 
    <a href="index.htm" title="Best Real Estate Website">
      <img src="image1013.png" alt="Best Real Estate Website" style="float:right;margin:10px;width:150px;height:80px" />
    </a>
    <h1>Landshoppe</h1>
    <h3>The Property Destination</h3></div>
    <div class="lpanel">
      <div>
        <h3>Landshoppe</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Established in 2009 as an offline Real Estate Agency, Landshoppe became a Free Real Estate portal in 2010 to cater to
        the online demand for quick and easy property search/sale and rentals. Indigenously developed, the portal has evolved
        continously - offering online and offline real estate services.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="lpanel2">
        <h3>Other Projects</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Project 1
          <br />Location 1</li>
          <li>Project 2
          <br />Location 2</li>
          <li>Project 3
          <br />Location 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rpanel">
      <div class="rpanel1">
      <!-- <iframe width="260" height="250" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
                                scrolling="no"  src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Thane&amp;aq=&amp;sll=18.815427,76.775144&amp;sspn=7.710738,15.644531&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Thane,+Maharashtra&amp;ll=19.218331,72.97809&amp;spn=0.240504,0.488892&amp;t=m&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />
                                <small><a href="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Thane&amp;aq=&amp;sll=18.815427,76.775144&amp;sspn=7.710738,15.644531&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Thane,+Maharashtra&amp;ll=19.218331,72.97809&amp;spn=0.240504,0.488892&amp;t=m&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=A" style="color:#0000FF;">View Larger Map</a></small>-->
      <h3>Property Address</h3>Mr Parhar
      <br />9322633301 | parharbt@yahoo.com
      <br />www.parharestate.com</div>
      <div class="rpanel2">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="toemail" value="parharbt@yahoo.com" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="title" value="Mr" /> Message
        <br />
        <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="28"></textarea>
        <br />Name : 
        <input type="text" name="fname" />
        <br />Mobile : 
        <input type="text" name="fmob" />
        <br />Email : 
        <input type="text" name="fmail" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="msgsub" value="Send Message" /></form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="midpanel">
      <div class="middle1">
        <div class="middlemainimg">
          <img src="upload/New-Real-Estate-Projects-in-Murbad%20Karjat-7148Parhar9322633301.jpg"
          alt="NA PLOTS ON MURBAD-KARJAT HIGHWAY" />
        </div>
        <div class="middle1r">
          <h3>Na Plots On Murbad-karjat Highway</h3>
          <p>Available for sale on Murbad -Karjat Highway. NA Sanctioned Plots with Cement Pole Fencing with gate for each Plot.
          Electricity line available till each Plot.Rate 240-PSF Plot size 4475 sq feet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="middle2">
      <h3>Project Highlights</h3>* The Best Free Real Estate Website
      <br />* All properties and Property Related Services Available here
      <br />* Blogs and Question/Answers forums
      <br />* Free Member Pages and Project Pages</div>
      <div class="middle3">
        <div id="carousel">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="image1272.jpg" alt="image1272.jpg" class="imgcar" />
              <img src="image1526.jpg" alt="image1526.jpg" class="imgcar" />
              <img src="image1574.jpg" alt="image1574.jpg" class="imgcar" />
              <img src="image1077.jpg" alt="image1077.jpg" class="imgcar" />
              <img src="image7251.jpg" alt="image7251.jpg" class="imgcar" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="image1272.jpg" alt="image1272.jpg" class="imgcar" />
              <img src="image1526.jpg" alt="image1526.jpg" class="imgcar" />
              <img src="image1574.jpg" alt="image1574.jpg" class="imgcar" />
              <img src="image1077.jpg" alt="image1077.jpg" class="imgcar" />
              <img src="image7251.jpg" alt="image7251.jpg" class="imgcar" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- <div id="viewer">
<div><h3>Swimming Pool <br>(<span class="pointer" id="closev1" style="color:yellow">Click anywhere to Close</span>)</h3><img src="Images/pool_sunrise.jpg" alt="Swimming Pool" /></div>
<div><h3>Star Gazing <br>(<span class="pointer" id="closev2" style="color:yellow">Click anywhere to Close</span>)</h3><img src="Images/star-gazing.gif" alt="Star Gazing" /></div>
<div><h3>Passage <br>(<span class="pointer" id="closev3" style="color:yellow">Click anywhere to Close</span>)</h3><img src="Images/welcome3.jpg" alt="Passage" /></div>
<div><h3>Bon Fire <br>(<span class="pointer" id="closev4" style="color:yellow">Click anywhere to Close</span>)</h3><img src="Images/bonfire.jpg" alt="Bonfire" /></div>
<div><h3>Wash Room <br>(<span class="pointer" id="closev5" style="color:yellow">Click anywhere to Close</span>)</h3><img src="Images/washroom.jpg" alt="Wash Room" /></div>
<div><h3>Pool and Accomodation <br>(<span class="pointer" id="closev6" style="color:yellow">Click anywhere to Close</span>)</h3><img src="Images/room_pool.jpg" alt="Pool and Accomodation" /></div>
<div><h3>Lake <br>(<span class="pointer" id="closev7" style="color:yellow">Click anywhere to Close</span>)</h3><img src="Images/lake.jpg" alt="Lake" /></div>
<div><h3>Bed <br>(<span class="pointer" id="closev8" style="color:yellow">Click anywhere to Close</span>)</h3><img src="Images/bed.jpg" alt="Bed" /></div>
</div>-->
      </div>
      <div class="middle4">
        <h3>Locality Highlights</h3>
        <img style="margin:0px auto" src="locationmap.png" width="150" height="100" />
      </div>
      <div class="middle4r">
      <h3>Distances to nearby facilities</h3>* Railway Station : _ Km/s
      <br />* Hospital : _ Km/s
      <br />* School : _ Km/s
      <br />* Market : _ Km/s
      <br /></div>
      <div class="middlelast">
      <h3>Property View</h3>
      <img src="image12701.jpg" alt="image12701.jpg" />
      <img src="image12741.jpg" alt="image12741.jpg" /> 
      <img src="image15841.jpg" alt="image15841.jpg" />
      <img src="image15911.jpg" alt="image15911.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottompanel">
      <ul>
        <li>About us</li>
        <li>Contact us</li>
        <li>Our offices</li>
        <li>Sites</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jav2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it the FLOAT format ? Because the left and right floats are getting messed up. I have googled a lot but couldn't make out what could possibly be the reason ?  It is also behaving different on my local machine and the server ! In the local machine, the right/left floats are not working and on the server, the middle div is laying out below after the right/left divs.

On the server, my IE6 and IE7 warnings are throwing up on IE9 too !

The url

http://www.landshoppe.com/project-page?dafid=30

Comment: I like your title...should be reverse though :)

Comment: :-) @Mr.Alien Well the layout in IE9 seems to follow that :-) Any ideas ?

Comment: I have fiddled around with the middle div widths and now have managed to render a presentable page on ie9 too. Though it is not exactly like ff or chrome !

Comment: @user2444559, You have to be more specific. Just copy pasting your page's full HTML and CSS wont help us or yourself much. be specific. How do you expect us to spend time sorting out your exact problem.

Comment: The problem is, I had updated the post, two fold; 1. The layout renders differently in ff/chrome and ie9. I am not sure whether it is because of the float or width 2. It is rendering differently on local machine and server. I hv updated the server url in the post.

Comment: Your code contains `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />` so of course it mis-behaves in IE9 -- you're telling it to.

Comment: @Spudley I missed that, still doesn't render properly in IE10 when I change it to standards mode through the IE dev tools. See my answer.

Comment: @MichaelLawton - setting it to standards mode in IE10 dev tools fixes it for me.

Comment: So the left and right panels are spaced out further? I tried it again and definitely not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the `lpanel`. The images on the `toppanel` are affecting the floats.

```
<div class="lpanel" style="clear: both;">
```

Don't use inline styles in production though.

@Spudley mentioned you have `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />` in your code, note that this should never be used in production of a new site, it is intended to help keep old non-standards compliant sites (i.e. built to accommodate for bugs in older versions) working in newer versions of IE.